# How to query list of users and hours they worked today in microsoft team foundation server, tfs?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

In Team Foundation Server (TFS), currently I am able to query the work items (bugs, tasks) by @CurrentIterationPath and status (closed etc.). But I am in need of fetching all users who worked today and the number of hours they logged. Could anyone out there help please?

I am using tfs 2015.

Answer (score 0):

**CAVEAT** what you ask is a bad practice and I always advise against. TFS is not a time entry tool: it is designed to support development team in being agile not to support accounting! If you need that there are tools that extend/integrate with TFS, designed for that purpose.

That said, there is no OOB report, query or API that will extract similar information.
A possibility is to use an Excel Pivot Table that reorder the export of a WIQL query. See [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/excel/create-status-and-trend-excel-reports) and [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel) for Excel integration with TFS.

Another path is to write a [SSRS custom report](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd380714.aspx) but I doubt it offers all data you asked for and it is a non trivial exercise IMHO.